# How to mount a filesystem that also has remote filesystems mounted

Tags: networking, ssh, amazon-ec2, ftp, filesystems

I am trying to create a system for our developers to be able to use libraries that MUST be retained at the client's site.  We are not allowed to download these libraries to develop off locally, but have to use them off of the client's owned server.  Our initial idea (which hasn't worked yet) was this:

- Create an EC2 instance (Linux 2 box).
- Mount that instance to each customer's FTP/SSH system using sshfs/ftpfs.
- Each developer uses sshfs/ftpfs to mount the EC2 instance to their machine.

This would maintain that the library is only owned by the client, but we can mount it and include it in an IDE locally.  So far each individual step worked, but the client filesystem does not appear on the local filesystem (it does appear on the EC2 instance).

So, my question is - is there any way to get this to work with our intended approach, or is this a lost cause?  Are there any other approaches that may work to achieve the desired result (which is to have a single mount point for the developers owned by us that can have access to X number of external mount points)?

Comment: What type of instance is it and how is the mount being done?

Comment: Sorry, I added an edit to specify the type of EC2, but it's an AWS Linux 2 box, and on the box we were using the sshfs to mount the client site, then using the same thing to mount the ec2 to the local mac.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with EC2.

In a unix nfs system you would need to mount each file system separately.  Nested NFS is a bad idea, so you would mount them independently then make a symbolic link tree that mirrored the directory structure.

I think that this is the approach you need to take.

If the client's system is organized

```
faraway:/
faraway:/majorfilesystem
faraway:/majorfilesystem/otherfarserver/
faraway:/majorfilesystem/thirdfarserver/
faraway:/filesystem/fourthfarserver/afilesystem.
```

Then you set up something like

```
local:/devmountpoints
local:/devmountpoints/otherfarserver
local:/devmountpoints/thirdfarserver
local:/devmountpoints/afilesystem
```

Then `/clientlib` is a tree of symbolic links that makes your local mount points have the same relative path structure as the mount points on the client's site.

While in theory you only need one link per foreign mount point, because of the way stat calls work you may be better off to create sysmlinks to every foreign directory, or even every foreign file for performance reasons.  Mounted file stat results aren't usually cached as agressively as local ones.  If you don't have to do a chain of stat calls to something far away, you *should* get better performance.